# I have got the Exception [DEBUG|Exception: System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL. ] on SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

When i have executed my code i got the exception **System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.** . Kindly assist me.

```
string query3 ='select id, accountId, UserOrGroupId, AccountAccessLevel, Account.Products_Serviced_by_GFL__c, Account.RecordType.Name 
                  from AccountShare where id =:SharedAccIds ';
query3= query3+'AND accountId =:(select id from account where Products_Serviced_by_GFL__c includes ('+prodType+') AND RecordType.Name IN :regionlist)';
list<AccountShare>aftersharedAcclist=database.query(query3);
system.debug('aftersharedAcclist: '+aftersharedAcclist);
```

Comment: Is there no indication of the position of the error in the message you get? I'm thinking it may be the ":" character here "AND accountId =:(select" but without seeing the full error it's difficult to know.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121537/only-variable-references-are-allowed-in-dynamic-soql-sosl?rq=1 this may be helpful as reference

Comment: Is `SharedAccIds`  is a collection ? If so Use ' ... Id IN:'+SharedAccIds

Comment: @Sarvesh, Yes  it is a collection.

Comment: @Matthew Whisker, Complete exception is :  USER_DEBUG [199]|DEBUG|Exception: System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.

Comment: @Ankitverma, ok,  have tried the above my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this needs to be a dynamic query, and if there isn't a good reason for it to be dynamic, you should just make it a static query (i.e. use `[SELECT Id FROM Object WHERE Filters]` instead of building your query as a string and using `Database.query()`).

The main benefit of dynamic queries is that it allows you to dynamically determine things (fields to query (which could be defined by a fieldset), the object, the filters), but you're not making use of any of that.

That said, your query syntax has a few basic errors.

From what I can see, the issues are all on your second line
`query3 = query3 + 'AND accountId =:(select id from account where Products_Serviced_by_GFL__c includes ('+prodType+') AND RecordType.Name IN :regionlist)';`

- You could use `query3 += <string>` instead of `query3 = query3 + <string>`
- The colon `:` is only used for variable binds, your use of it with your semi-join is incorrect (`AND field = :(semi-join)` is not valid syntax, it's just `AND field = (semi-join)`)

  - ^ This one is probably the root of your error message
- `INCLUDES` is an operator specifically for multi-picklists, double check to ensure `Products_Serviced_by_GFL__c` is indeed a multi-picklist
- If `prodType` is a collection, you'd want to do some processing (prior to your query) to turn it into a string